# JSONObject vs JSONArray Swift

Tags: json, swift, http, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

Im trying to do a PUSH HTTP Request and im getting an error describing that i need to supply a JSON Array and not a JSONObject, how do i create an Array from my single object, is it possible to do so?

```
func printdata(){
  let myJsonDict: [String:AnyObject] = [
            "action": "Websites",
            "method":"school_webpage",
            "tid":2,
            "data":["schoolId":14273],
            "type":"rpc"
        ]
  do{
      let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(myJsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            HTTPPostJSON("http://wwww.oncoursesystems.com/json.axd/direct/router", data:jsonObject ) { (response, error) -> Void in
                print(response);
            }
       }
       catch{

       }
}

func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
       (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                callback("", error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                callback(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String, nil)
            }
   }

   task.resume()
}

func HTTPPostJSON(url: String,  data: NSData, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {

   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") 
   request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
   request.HTTPBody = data
   HTTPsendRequest(request, callback: callback)
}
```

My method call

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    names = HtmlController.loadData() as NSArray as! [String]
    names.removeAtIndex(0)
    clean()
    refreshController = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WebpageController.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshController)
    printdata()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this, becuase currently I am using a string for the body of my POSTs. It has been working for me, so I haven't bothered to do something else, but I wouldn't mind making my future code cleaner.

Comment: `i need to supply a JSON Array and not a JSONObject` There's some vocabulary confusion here: a JSON object is always either a Dictionary or an Array. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a POST request?

This works for me:

```
func HTTPPostJSON(url: String,  data: AnyObject, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")    
   request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: [])
   HTTPsendRequest(request, callback: callback)
}
```

Note the method signature, pass your data as ["String": AnyObject] and handle the serialization inside the HTTPPostJSON method. I think part of what's wrong might be related to passing formatted json (when using the pretty options).

**Edit**:

Based on your comments, have you updated your print method to cater for the new method signature? it should be something along the lines of:

```
func printdata(){
  let myJsonDict: [String:AnyObject] = [
        "action": "Websites",
        "method":"school_webpage",
        "tid":2,
        "data":["schoolId":14273],
        "type":"rpc"]

  HTTPPostJSON("http://wwww.oncoursesystems.com/json.axd/direct/router", data:myJsonDict) { 
     (response, error) -> Void in
       print(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your HTTPPostJSON method working in context of the methods i have above? When i use your method i still receive the same error

Comment: im calling it in view did load, please see my edited post

Comment: Have you updated the method call inside print so that it passes the dictionary without serializing first? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes i updated it, It still, however, returns the same error

Comment: Oh! I think your problem is related with your myJasonDic dictionary. You can check if its valid by using _NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(myJasonDic)_ It might be having troubles with your nested arrays.

Comment: Im getting true, so my JSONobject must be valid, could there be any other possible error?

Comment: I'm unsure mate, try stepping in with the debugger from the top down to catch where its happening, and I would also try with a simpler data dictionary to discard any issues there.